# New chat theme usability issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

Perhaps I'm the only one seeing this:

[image]

I *think* the word `help` is the leftmost option, but I copied a bit more just in case.  My eyesight is pretty good, but I can't really read anything other than `policy | mobile` without straining.

Comment: On my screen, it is "mobile" that fades out into bliss. Since the links are right aligned and the background is attached left, where you hit the clouds changes a little, but ya it's a little rough :)

Comment: I confirm that I see it like this. My screen resolution is 1366x768.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could easily be solved by aligning the background to the right so that you can reasonably predict where the text will fall on top of it:

```
#input-area {
    background-position: top right;
}
```

Comment: I still think the white on light blue is a usability flaw no matter where on the background the menu falls.

Comment: Good idea; done.

Comment: @balpha: Well, I was wrong it seems.  That does help tremendously. Thanks!

Comment: @balpha http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9745249#9745249

Answer (score 2):

I have the opposite issue (I'm assuming screen size comes into play here)

[image]