# The chat login message is unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

When entering a Christianity chat room prior to logging in, the login text is nearly impossible to read. Perhaps a dark blue would be better than white-on-white?

My screen resolution is 1280x800. The problem exists with both IE 10 and Opera 12 on Windows 8.

Related (and resolved): [New chat theme usability issue](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1778/4188)

[image: Chat login text]

Answer (score 5):

This has been completed and it will be deployed in the next build.